# JavaScript: Get non-repeating items from 2d array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Compare 2d array of objects and convert it into single array of objects by getting the unique items (non-repeating in terms of id) using Javascript.

**Sample input:**

```
const data = [
  [ { name: 'x', id: 1 }, { name: 'a', id: 13 }, { name: 'a', id: 14 }, { name: 'a', id: 15 }, { name: 'a', id: 16 } ],
  [ { name: 'y', id: 12 }, { name: 'a', id: 13 }, { name: 'a', id: 14 }, { name: 'a', id: 15 }, { name: 'a', id: 16 } ],
  [ { name: 'z', id: 22 }, { name: 'a', id: 13 }, { name: 'a', id: 14 }, { name: 'a', id: 15 }, { name: 'a', id: 16 } ]
];
```

**Expected output:**

```
const out = [
  { name: 'a', id: 1 }, 
  { name: 'b', id: 12 }, 
  { name: 'b', id: 22 }
]
```

Comment: The provided output doesnot match with the input. Provide the corrrect data set for input and output. Also mention what have you attempted so far.

Comment: To rephrase, there isn't an *obvious* way to get from your input to your output, it's not clear what you're trying to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), convert the 2d array into one
- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over the latter while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the id is the `key` and the count is the `value`
- Using [`Map#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries), get the list of id-count pairs from the Map. Then, using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), get the ids whose count is 1. Finally, using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), get the list of resulting ids
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), iterate over the flattened array of objects and return the elements whose ids belong to the non-repeating ids list

```js
const data = [
  [ { name: 'x', id: 1 }, { name: 'a', id: 13 }, { name: 'a', id: 14 }, { name: 'a', id: 15 }, { name: 'a', id: 16 } ],
  [ { name: 'y', id: 12 }, { name: 'a', id: 13 }, { name: 'a', id: 14 }, { name: 'a', id: 15 }, { name: 'a', id: 16 } ],
  [ { name: 'z', id: 22 }, { name: 'a', id: 13 }, { name: 'a', id: 14 }, { name: 'a', id: 15 }, { name: 'a', id: 16 } ]
];

const arr = data.flat();
const idCountMap = arr.reduce((map, { id }) => map.set(id, (map.get(id) ?? 0) + 1), new Map);
const nonRepeatingIds = 
  [...idCountMap.entries()]
  .filter(([ id, count ]) => count === 1)
  .map(([ id ]) => id);
const nonRepeatingItems = arr.filter(({ id }) => nonRepeatingIds.includes(id));

console.log(nonRepeatingItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting the use case in two parts.

**Part 1 : Concat the array of objects to a new array**

```
var array = [];
data.forEach(val => {
    array = [...array, ...val];
});
```

**Part 2 : Find the unique values in the new array**

```
const result = [];
const map = new Map();
for (const item of array) {
    if(!map.has(item.id)){
        map.set(item.id, true);    // set any value to Map
        result.push({
            id: item.id,
            name: item.name
        });
    }
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to loop the array of array and check if you already have added the id or not. In this way you can make the id unique in the result

```
const data= [
[{name:"x" , id:1},{name:"a" , id:13},{name:"a" , id:14},{name:"a" , id:15},{name:"a" , id:16},],
[{name:"x" , id:1},{name:"a" , id:13},{name:"a" , id:14},{name:"a" , id:15},{name:"a" , id:16},],
[{name:"x" , id:1},{name:"a" , id:13},{name:"a" , id:14},{name:"a" , id:15},{name:"a" , id:16},]
]

//loop for each array and filter
var addedId = [];


//init result
var out = [];


//loop array
data.forEach(function(arr){
  //loop element in array
  arr.forEach(function(obj){
      // check if the id has been already added to the result
      if(!addedId.includes(obj.id)){
        addedId.push (obj.id);
        out.push(obj); 
      }
  })
})
```